# How to call restful webservice using spring integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am new to spring integration. to make a rest webservice call, i have below configuration.

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway
    url="#{appProperties['rootUrl']}#{appProperties['myMethod']}"
    request-channel="myRequestChannel" reply-channel="myResponseChannel" >
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

But i should also pass authentication information (username and password) to make a webservice call. how can i send authentication information through `http:outbound-gateway`?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a custom ClientHttpRequestFactory and provide it to the adapter using the `request-factory` attribute.

Either use the `CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory` with a custom `HttpClient`, or subclass the `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` and override the `prepareConnection` method to add the credentials.

Googling "resttemplate basic authentication" will provide several examples, including http://blog.mitemitreski.com/2012/03/basic-authentication-with-resttemplate.html